# YAML form columnar not working

Tags: css, yaml-css

Anyone familiar with YAML here? Somehow columnar in YAML forms seems not to work for me. Also ym-full has no effect. What am I doing wrong? http://www.kine-stammheim.ch/kontakt.html

And how can I enlarge the margin between the border and the form elements? I think the elements are a bit too close to the border...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some classes have only be introduced in version 4.1.0. I updated YAML and now everything works fine.